# Optimize control loop?

Tags: control, ros, navigation, optimization, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I'm constantly getting warnings like

> Control loop missed its desired rate of 5.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.2028 seconds

using `move_base` to drive my robot around. Obviously something is taking pretty long within the control loop. What do you think, how could I optimize it to reduce the time a control loop cycle takes?

This is what my current `rosgraph` looks like:

[20130921_rosgraph.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/13797746122976358.png)

My personal assumption is that there are too many nodes between /MoveBase and /udpOutgoingInterface.

Thanks for your help!

Cheers,
Hendrik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81866/optimize-control-loop?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2013-09-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-09-21**:
Did you compile the code, or are you using the debs?

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-09-22**:
I'm using the debs. Do you think, compiling the stack explicitly with compiler optimizations for my arch would make that much of a difference?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-09-22**:
The debs should be correct, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

There are some advices about lack of processing power on [Navigation Tuning Guide](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide)

some advices may be useful for you

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2013-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2